# How to get reliable call-backs with WCF using NetTcpBinding

Tags: .net, wcf, callback, nettcpbinding

I am planning to use the NetTcpBinding for an application that needs to keep a hand-full of clients in sync.

Whenever there is a change of state at the server, all the connected clients must be informed.

However I need the clients to automatically reconnect if there is a network problem, any outstanding callbacks from the server for the given client should not get lost.
I also need to the client’s GUI code to be informed if the connection to the sever is lost and cannot be recreated. (or if the server restarts)

> Does the NetTcpBinding with
>   WS-ReliableMessaging give me this “out
>   of the box”?

Comment: Are you attached to using TCP/IP?  I'm wondering if messaging could help you and therefore your clients would never need to know if the server was up or down, the would just care about consuming messages.

Comment: @foosnazzy, I rather not use messaging queues due to all the support issues in getting customers to create them on their machines.  However I will consider them if we get too many complaints about problems with TCP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this article here: [Introduction to Reliable Messaging with the Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480191.aspx) under the section titled "Reliable Messaging Session Options". Specifically the MaxRetryCount property may be what you're looking for.