# What does the Reliable property mean in netTcpBinding

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding, reliability

The netTcpBidning has a reliable property, but the documentation doesn't state what it does.

For instance: Do it send keep-alives over the connection? Do it reconnect if connection is lost?

Answer (score 2):

Try

[How to get reliable call-backs with WCF using NetTcpBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783422/how-to-get-reliable-call-backs-with-wcf-using-nettcpbinding)

and

http://netindonesia.net/blogs/kasim.wirama/archive/2007/12/12/implementing-reliable-session-in-wcf.aspx

Comment: Neither of those pages says anything about reconnect attempts. Or am I missing something?

Comment: TCP is reliale by nature I think you need to read up on the difference between transport and message reliability.  http://codeidol.com/csharp/wcf/WCF-Essentials/Reliability/

Comment: And http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731375.aspx seems to indicated that some comminucation is required before the channel is faulted.